# How to filter text file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, duplicates

I have a file that contains text of 1000+ features. Some features in the file are the same, but different users typed it in different way, for example:

User1 typed: Google 
User2 typed: google (all small letters)
User3 typed: Google, (comma at the end)

It is clear that all of the above have the same feature.
My goal is to filter the features file, so that the output will have unique features only without any duplicates.

I need to do this using Matlab, anyone knows how I can do this?

Its really similar to txt file, I have three columns, row number, description of the feature and the feature itself:

.

.

.

909 job_title:non-ascii_909
910 job_title:non-ascii_910
911 job_title:non-ascii_911
912 last_name:aaron
913 last_name:adam
.

.

I already read it on matlab, simply dragged the file in there. and I know how to load it into a matrix.

lets say if two features have the same sequence of characters and the difference is Lower/upper case , space, or another character then its a duplicate.

Many thanks

Comment: Be more specific. How does the file contain those features? Have you already read that file into Matlab, and in that case how? What are your criteria to declare to features as duplicate: lower/upper case? Spaces? Dashes?

Comment: Edited. Is there another thing?

Comment: You might want to consider using edit distance, like this [FLX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32449-edit-distances) example.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to read in each line, parsing out only the text after the : (as I understand what you have written, that is the part you want to remove duplicates from).  When you read in the text you are interested in, you can convert it to lowercase (you could also do uppercase if you please) and then remove the duplicate entries at the end.

A quick pass on how to do something like that:

```
entries = {};
full_lines = {};
idx = 1;

fid=fopen('\PATH\TO\FILE.txt','r');
tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
   full_lines(idx) = cellstr(tline);
   [tkn rem] = strtok(tline,':');
   [tkn rem] = strtok(rem,':');
   lower_case = lower(tkn);
   entries(idx) = cellstr(lower_case);

   idx = idx + 1;
   tline = fgets(fid);    
end

fclose(fid);

no_duplicates = unique(entries);
full_lines_no_duplicates = full_lines(indices);
```

This goes through your file line-by-line, storing the text after the ':' in an array as all lowercase and then removing the duplicate values.  This leaves you with only unique values.  It also stores the full lines in case you need them, the full_lines_no_duplicates variable will contain the entire lines from the file without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the data imported into Matlab. I would start with looping through each of the lines, and 'fixing' each of the features to meet your qualifications.

```
for i=1:length(feature_vector)
    line=feature_vector(i); //extract line from vector
    //clean 'line' data
    feature_vector(i)=line; //re-insert cleaned line to vector
end
```

First, it seems you want to be case-insensitive when considering the features. To do this, just convert each feature to its all lowercase counterpart as such:

```
line=lower(line);
```

where line is just one of the string features that you obtain inside your loop.

Next, you seem to want to remove all special characters from the features, and can be achieved as:

```
line(~ismember(line,['a':'z'])) = '';
```

this will remove any letter inside of your feature that is not a letter of the alphabet.

After you have done this for the entire dataset, you should now be left with a cell array of features that are all lowercase and contain only letters of the alphabet.

You can remove duplicates and obtain a list of only the unique features of the cell array by using the 'unique()' function of Matlab:

```
[U,IDX]=unique(feature_vector);
```

Hope this helps!